# how to pass a database name as a parameter in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

My requirement is i want to pass "use databasename as parameter in SSRS Report".

When the user run the report system will ask to pick the database name from the parameter lists and these values i am retriving from "select name from sys.databases"

Once user select the value from the parameter that value must passed to 
"use databasename"[Database name value from parameter]

For eg: parameter name : @param1
so in the report SQL Query can i use like "use @param1" go and select statement

Is it possible? Please advise.

Comment: Are you saying you want to change the database that is used by SSRS at run time? Or do you just need to show a list of database names as a filter for your report?

Answer (score 0):

You can build the query dynamically and use sp_executesql to run it.
Below is an example where I've used this to return a list of tables, views, stored procedures and functions for a given database name passed in a parameter @DatabaseName

```
DECLARE @SQLScript nvarchar(4000)

SET @SQLScript = 
'USE ' +@DatabaseName + 
'SELECT 
    S.name as SchemaName,
    O.name as ObjectName,
    O.Type,
    REPLACE(O.type_desc,''_'','' '') as TypeDescription,
    O.create_date as CreatedDate,
    O.modify_date as ModifiedDate
FROM 
    sys.objects O
JOIN
    sys.schemas S
    ON
    O.schema_id = S.schema_id
WHERE
    O.type IN (''FN'',''IF'',''P'',''TF'',''U'',''V'') '

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLScript
```

An alternate method is to create a data source using an embedded connection (this won’t work for a shared data source reference) and build the connection string as an expression.

From your data source properties ensure embedded connection is selected, click the expression (fx) button and build your connection string but substitute in your parameter (DatabaseName in my example) for the Intial Catalog value.

```
="Data Source=YourServerName;Initial Catalog=" + Parameters!DatabaseName.Value
```

Once you set an expression based connection string it can no longer be evaluated at design time. When you come to create your dataset you won’t be able to run any queries in the Query Designer or Refresh Fields in Dataset Properties.  Not a major issue, just use a regular connection string and once the report is working switch it to an expression based one.

You can also use this method to pass the server name as a parameter too.

Comment: http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2012/08/how-to-use-dynamic-data-sources-in-your.html